Does cobalt form square planar complexes?
So I came across a question where we were required to identify the possible central metal atom using the following clues. 
An aqueous solution of metal ion M1 reacts separately with reagents Q and R in excess to give tetrahedral and square planar complexes, respectively. An aqueous solution of another metal ion M2 always forms tetrahedral complexes with these reagents. 
Q was HCl and R was KCN.
The options had both Ni 2+ and Co 2+ ions as a possibility for M1. 
The answer given is the one having Ni. Why cannot Co be the answer?
One explanation was given that only d8 configurations form square planar complexes. Is this correct?

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/tetrahedral-or-square-planar

Technically, square planar cobalt complexes can be formed with specially designed carbene ligands [1]. Such species may serve as catalysts for electron-transfer processes. But yes, in most common cases we do need a $d^8$ metal core to favor this geometry, and given the low second ionization energy of most transition metals forming such a core with only one positive charge (as $\ce{Co^{+}})$ is not favored in most chemical settings.
Any introductory treatment of ligand-field theory or even crystal-field theory explains this. Basically when you have a square planar geometry, the $d$ orbital with the lobes pointing directly  at the ligands ($d_{x^2-y^2}$ with the usual coordinate definitions) takes up a major part of the sigma antibonding interactions that both theories posit between the metal $d$ orbitals and the ligand sigma orbitals. So the configuration is most stabilized when just that disfavored $d$ orbital is left vacant and the others are occupied; thus $d^8$.
Reference

Zhenbo Mo, Yuxue Li, Hung Kay Lee‡l, and Liang Deng. "Square-Planar Cobalt Complexes with Monodentate N-Heterocyclic Carbene Ligation: Synthesis, Structure, and Catalytic Application". Organometallics 2011, 30, 17, 4687–4694.
https://doi.org/10.1021/om200527y.

